# iOS error with Firebase Auth Sign In using Twitter credentials

Tags: ios, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I have a iOS Firebase app that supports Twitter login, but occasionally the `signIn(with: credential` call randomly fails and I can't figure out why.

First the user signs in with Twitter (which never fails), then I use the Twitter session to get the credentials, and then I use those credentials to sign in with Firebase which sometimes fails.

Here's the complete code

```
func twitterLogin(_ done:@escaping (_ user: FIRUser?, _ err: Error?) -> Void) {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn() { session, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            done(nil, error)
            return
        }

        let credential = FIRTwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: session!.authToken, secret: session!.authTokenSecret)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (signUser, error) in
            //User is signed in

            // ERROR OCCURS HERE. ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED

            done(signUser, error)
        })
    }
}
```

Here's the exact error message I'm getting.

```
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000442c10 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
code = 400;
errors =     (
            {
        domain = global;
        message = "Network error while to fetch VERIFY_CREDENTIAL from TWITTER.";
        reason = invalid;
    }
);
message = "Network error while to fetch VERIFY_CREDENTIAL from TWITTER.";
}}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})
```

I've tried to specifically search for the error message I'm getting **"Network error while to fetch VERIFY_CREDENTIAL from TWITTER."** but I can't find any solution. I found some posts which I believe were in Japanese but I couldn't understand their solution.

I even looked at Firebases iOS Auth errors here 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors
but the error key **FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey** isn't even listed as a possible error for `signInWithCredential:completion:`

Comment: I'm getting the same error using Firebase for the web: "Network error while to fetch VERIFY_CREDENTIAL from TWITTER." It also only happens "occasionally", and seemingly to some Twitter users more than others. I even tried implementing my own auth backend function to get the auth token and secret directly from Twitter, using them to sign in like this: `var credential = firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(token, secret); firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);` but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Same here using Firebase for at least 2 months now. Firebase says it is not them. Twitter is not responding. Other existing apps using Twitter Auth w Firebase is working normally. In the meantime, as a shaky but only workaround, I am implementing a 3-retry logic with some time delay. Even with that, it clears about 50% of the time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same error. Example at codepen:

https://codepen.io/mosse/pen/KmGMap

```html
<button class="login">login</button>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDfJ5KuDofcZpahzl4H3XTl4f6R65gUyrQ",
    authDomain: "authtest-3a944.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "authtest-3a944",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login").click(function(){
      var providerObj = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(providerObj)
       .then(result => {
        console.log('success')
          console.log(result.user)
       })
       .catch( err => {
         console.log('failure')
         console.log(err.message)
      })
    });
});
</script>
```

Firebase support suggest the cause is due to an unreliable Twitter endpoint, but haven't suggested any solution.

An older project using Firebase 2.3.2 does not replicate the error, which suggests that there should be a Firebase solution to me.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed by Twitter. Anyone still seeing the error?